# How to limit number of Customizable Options customer can select?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I have added multiple Customizable Options(e.g. Extra Buffalo Cheese,Extra Aioli,Extra Hollandaise,Extra Caesar Dressing) for products as shown in the image below. I want to restrict this option selection to a maximum to 2 only. basically, the user can select any 2 values for extra not more than two.

Is there a way to achieve this with CMS or through code as I have no idea here ? or Any other better way to do achieve the same.

[image: Customizable Options]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy and override default template in your custom theme `app/design/frontend/Your/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/composite/fieldset/options/view/checkable.phtml` and add below code at end of file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){ 
    $('input.product-custom-option').on('change', function(evt) {
       if($('input.product-custom-option').parent().find('input.product-custom-option:checked').length >= 2) {
           $('input.product-custom-option').parent().find('input.product-custom-option:not(:checked)').attr("disabled", true);
       }else{
           $('input.product-custom-option').parent().find('input.product-custom-option:not(:checked)').removeAttr("disabled");
       }
    });
  });
</script>
```